# Voting down because idea in the question is wrong?

Tags: discussion, downvotes

What is wrong with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23835070/should-a-helper-classs-structure-be-based-on-input-type-or-output-type) question? (Basically question is "should I use approach A or B" where there is another better option not mentioned in the post, but shown in answer).

It got -4 votes quickly but I don't really see anything particularly bad with the question - have good title, clear sample code, definitely not "useful just for me", does not look immediate duplicate.

My guess people think both options suggested in the question were bad and down-vote based on that - would it be valid reason for SO? Or maybe I'm missing something and should have voted down too?

What would make such question not to attract down-votes?

EDIT: note that there were no close votes that seem to rule out "question is opinion based" voting, which makes voting reasons interesting for me.

Comment: We can only guess at why someone else downvoted your post.  We can never *know*.  As always, lok at the downvote tool tip.  They readers likely felt that the post was not well researched, not useful, or unclear.  It doesn't seem unclear to me, so one of the other two seems most likely.

Comment: I can make an educated guess, though.  The question is purely opinion-based; without specific software requirements, it's not really satisfactorily answerable in its present form, although the current answer posted there is a good one because it points out the false dichotomy present in the question.

Comment: I didn't downvote it, but I do find it a bit too brief. It is hard to get a sense of the context. I get the sense that the OP is missing something (important) that the question does not clue us into and that we can't help them without knowing more.

Comment: Very much opinion-based. Surprising that it got so many down-votes without attracting a single close-vote though.

Comment: Overall, it seems a little too subjective. On the plus side, you did at least include code snippets. That's more than a lot of posts have...

Comment: People will do what they do. If you want upvotes, then look at the structure of upvoted questions and mimic what they do.

Comment: Isn't that someone else's post the OP is referring to?

Comment: Looks like a basic question. The kind of a question who no one wants to answer. Idk, it's not the kind of a question who I downvote, but it's not the kind of a question who I like to see on stackoverflow.

If you see the answer, the question is so simple that in any OOP course/class/book/introduction you get the answer.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: there are many people who cannot vote on close, but yeah... they should at least leave a downvote reason. It is amazing how much activity a meta discussion triggers on posts though... Is there any plan to lock the posts in question while discussing it?

Comment: It seems to me that the question being referred to should be moved to `programmers.stackexchange.com`. It seems like quite a valid conceptual question. (I don't have enough rep to vote for that, though.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Disclaimer:  you're free to use your votes however you like, so long as you're not actively committing vote fraud (excessive votes for any one person, up or down).

> What would make such question not to attract down-votes?

This question isn't going to be able to not attract downvotes, since it's extremely subjective and not one of the questions we want to tout as a "good" sample of what to ask.  For instance, what one person's helper class may hold is different than what mine may hold.  There's no canonical, reasonable answer to this.

*If* the question could be salvaged to be less broad/subjective, then *maybe* it wouldn't be hit with such downvotes.  But that's a pretty slim if for questions of this caliber.

Comment: Looks like summary: subjective + too broad. Looks like possible recommendation - be way more specific with context OR possibly show more research (but in this case probably not be asked on SO - maybe programmers).

Answer (score -8):

Are we here for upvotes or downvotes? That's of course sad to get down by community (given sometimes people can not even formulate their question properly because lack of knowledge or experience), but if you give answer - sadness will be compensated! Guys I know that - because I used to ask stupid, trivial questions. That's why I have this name.

Comment: I'm *really* not sure what you're getting at with this.

Comment: Not sure how this related to the question.

Comment: Not me. You. All of you. Let's assume asker comes here not to troll you. He needs help. Generic questions, usually asked by people who miss context or whole idea need first clarification and then narrowing. It is really a hard work. To educate the asker. To explain him that his question does not have proper answer because of specific reasons. Those who come here for upvotes and badges will not bother. As soon as they get authority to give downvotes or sh*t on others, who asked question they can not answer quickly to get a badge, they do it. This is IMHO. I used to experience it myself here.

Comment: Sorry if it sounds as moaning. It's up to you how to treat the feedback.

Comment: *"Are we here for upvotes or downvotes?"* Neither. We are here to give and receive help. If you're here for votes (of any kind), you're here for the wrong reason.

Comment: @CodyGray ` If you're here for votes (of any kind), you're here for the wrong reason.` Then do away with points, badges, etc.  I'm sure that will go over well.

Comment: @McGarnagle I didn't say that reputation points had no purpose. They measure one's experience with the site and its policies, and therefore regulate who has access to moderation tools. They are absolutely essential. But they're not the primary reason to answer questions here.

Comment: @CodyGray `But they're not the primary reason to answer questions here`. true - in theory - or not even this.