# Why a Zero Voted Question is Considered as a Bad One?

Tags: discussion, questions, voting

A number of my question attract zero voting. I am a bit surprised that neutral attitude is considered as the bad one. Voting itself is a subjective process, for some people the question could look broad, for some too narrow, it depends on the persons knowledge at the current moment. Some questions are well structured (following all the recommendations and patterns from Stack), they get the good and decent answers (it means people in the same field understand them correctly) but they receive zero voting. You would say that it is subjective, and even depends on the people's view (some people just do not vote for the questions since the answers, not questions, help them to solve the issues). **Is it possible that subjective or neutral thing is considered as a negative in Stack community?** It is a negative one since I got the answer from the help center where zero vote questions stand at the same line with negatively voted.

For example, in the email from Help Center it was written: *"Your block was triggered automatically by the system; most of your posts have not been well-received by the community — meaning they were either downvoted or **not voted on at all**."*

p. s. I think the idea is here to attract people which can get the answers or professionals which can help other, not to attract people who make researches or likes-hunters like in facebook :-). Sometimes person is a good at his field, but not a good speaker about his field and vice versa. Actually, some people do not have free hours here to make wide researches on the topic, and only then ask the question.

Comment: "_But how is it possible that subjective or neutral thing is considered as a negative in Stack community_" do you have any examples?

Comment: Where in the help center did you read that "zero vote questions stand at the same line with negatively voted"?

Comment: I will edit with the example.

Comment: Can you edit with the link to the actual page as well? The page I had suspected you got it from, the on on [question bans](http://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans) doesn't have that particular phrasing.

Comment: At the same time, allow me to help clarify a bit of your confusion, as that wording is most definitely not clear. Zero score and negative score questions are _not_ in any way, shape, or form on equal footing. Zero score questions _are_ taken into account for the question ban algorithm, but from my understanding, it would take a lot more zero score questions than negative ones to get a ban. The page is only telling you that that is one of the factors for seeing your questions as not well received, not that zero score and negative score are equal in those terms.

Comment: @Kendra, thanks for clarifying more. But if that factor is included in that algorithm, even in a bit weaker form, it expresses a kind of attitude. Even a small minus is still a minus. This algorithm is created to ban the authors of the bad question, isn't it?

Comment: The thought behind it is if your questions aren't getting upvotes, they aren't necessarily useful. Now, that may not actually be the case, which is why it takes a lot more zero voted questions to get banned. The algorithm is indeed meant to stop users who aren't posting content of the quality we would like. However, there are other warnings that are supposed to show ahead of time and give you a wake-up call that you're heading for a brick wall.

Comment: @DariusMiliauskas the intent is to keep people who post useful questions on stack. If no one upvotes your questions, then chances are they are only useful to you, which makes them not aligned with Stack's ultimate goal.This is a harsh reality, but it is what it is. If your question isn't something other members of the community will use, then it's not up to the quality standards we have. The fact it's not considered as bad as downvoted posts proves that they are not on equal ground, even if 0-score isn't GOOD.

Comment: `Actually, some people do not have free hours here to make wide researches on the topic, and only then ask the question.` If you're going to ask poorly researched questions, then you're going to have to face the consequences of that, including getting question banned for repeatedly trying to take advantage of the community by not doing your part in the process.  The fact that you can't do what you want *is precisely why this site feature exists*.  Clearly it's doing its job.

Comment: @Kendra Useful or not - perhaps it is a better term. But then it means that the ban algorithm is to sort out unuseful question even if they are good. So, whats the point to ban the person who gives good questions (well structured) but not useful? I agree that a person is not useful for the popularity of Stack if he does not get upvotes.

Comment: @DariusMiliauskas We ban people that don't post useful content to prevent them from posting more non-useful content, and consuming resources of the site that could be better spent on useful content.

Comment: Well, this is not a zero-voted question.  Maybe you see the difference now?

Comment: @Servy ok, i see the point but than the recommendation to improve the questions is a bit contradictory. It the question by nature is not useful for the community, only for the person who asks, then even after the improvement it will remain like it.

Comment: @DariusMiliauskas You're making assumptions about what problem(s) the question has, and what improvements will be done.  Perhaps whatever problems the question has that cause it to not be useful can be improved.  Not all problems can be fixed, but plenty can, so the suggestion is appropriate.  It's not like it can know whether or not a given question is fixable.

Comment: @DariusMiliauskas not necessarily. You can broaden your question to encompass your original question, and make it broad enough that other users can find benefit in it. In any case, out of the 30+ questions you have at 0, I'd be surprised if NONE of them can benefit from improvement.

Comment: @Servy The question: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255987/voting-down-because-idea-in-the-question-is-wrong got 11 upvotes while this one - 11 downvotes. Could somebody explain the main difference from the point of view to the quality/useful? I think that question is more concrete, about asker's particular question, and only useful for himself, my question is more broader, and perhaps some people would have the same issues, but it is downvoted.

Comment: I dunno.  If OP is auto banned, maybe the team should take a look and be sure that this outcome is desirable in this case.

Comment: @DariusMiliauskas Meta is different than main, so using an example from Meta to show what you mean is a bad idea. (Unless you're actually asking about Meta to begin with.) Try to find some examples from main instead. While you're looking, you might even find/sort out the answer for yourself.

Comment: @DariusMiliauskas You may want to consider rephrasing the question to something more along the lines of "Does this happen?" with a more neutral tone.

Comment: @DariusMiliauskas That question got upvotes because it was someone looking for help improving his content.  This question is getting downvotes because you're proposing removing a feature that is doing its job in holding back unhelpful content.  The questions have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: @apaul34208 Why would he want to ask if it happens.  The system message is specificaly telling him that it does happen, so there's no question about that.  He's proposing that it be changed.

Comment: @DariusMiliauskas the question you linked is very neutral, makes no assumptions, and doesn't sound rant-y in the slightest. Yours feels a bit more rant-y, and includes parts where you say stuff like "I don't have time to do long research", which is frowned upon a bit. All in all, as Servy says, yours seems to suggest a change into the behavior, where the other one just asks why this happens...

Comment: @Servy Perhaps a "Why does this happen?", assuming that it does... There's a chance that the message is misleading or that it isn't as clear as it could be.

Answer (score 3):

The term you are looking for is [opportunity cost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opportunity_cost):

Any attention spent on one post can no longer be spent on the next one, which *might* be useful.

So, if that one wasn't worth looking at (and thus doesn't deserve an upvote), it wastes scarce attention even if it isn't bad enough to downvote.